# Cartesian product of two open intervals

Tags: metric-spaces

Show that the Cartesian product of two open intervals $(a, b)$ and $(c, d)$
in $\mathbb{R}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$. What can you say about the Cartesian product of
two open sets in $\mathbb{R}$?

This is an exercise in my book. I have complete the first half of the problem using following:
$\epsilon < \min\{|x-a|,|x-b|,|y-c|,|y-d|\}$ then the ball $B_\epsilon (x,y) \subset \square$

Coming to second part, I have no idea what the statement "What can you say about the Cartesian product of
two open sets in $\mathbb{R}$?" means

Please help me with this.

Comment: Can you generalize from the first problem to the second? Can you justify it rigorously?

Comment: @BrianTung so it will be: the cartesian product of two open sets (open intervals) in R is always open?

Comment: "the cartesian product of two open sets (open intervals) in R is always open?"  That sounds like a very reasonable possibility.  Is it true?  That's the obvious thing to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that the product of two open intervals is open in $\Bbb R^2$.

In fact,  if you eventually study the product topology (and box topology) you can say more:   the product of any finite number $n$ of open intervals is open in $\Bbb R^n$.

This can be taken even further,  to an infinite product,  $\Bbb R^{\omega}$ (for starters).  The box and product topologies no longer coincide then.  But any finite product of open intervals is open (in either).

Of course,  $\Bbb R$ can be replaced by any topological space, $X$,   and we can take a product of $I$ copies of $X$ for an index set $I$ of any cardinality. The box topology is then *finer*, since it's generated by arbitrary (even infinite)  products of open sets.